# Turtle Mock: MOCK_EXPECT fails if mocked class method returns a value

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, turtle-mock

I am a long time lurker in the board, and is needless to say that you guys are the best and I am grateful for all the times you saved my job. That is my first time post here and I hope I don't mess it up.

I am writing a C++ Boost application for Linux (Virtualized Ubuntu 16.04 amd_64) and am using Turtle Mock for the mocking framework and Boost Test for the testing framework. When I try to test a class which uses dependency injection technique, I mock the classes that need to be given to the testing class so I can verify the sequence of their invocation. S far so good, but the problem comes here.
 I am using MOCK_BASE_CLASS(MockAClass, AClass), to override the virtual methods of the real AClass, and use to new MockAClass to proceed with my tests. Let's say AClass has a virtual method int getTest(int), and MockAClass has MOCK_METHOD(getTest, 1, int(int)), after setting expectation and return value for the getTest method of MockAClass object, and invoking the method, the expectation which in most cases is MOCK_EXPECT(objMockAClass.getTest).at_least(1) is NEVER verified. I can control the return value, but the call is never verified as it happened. This only occurs if the function returns a value (for ex. if the function is void getTest(int) then the verification will pass).

I am attaching a simple PoC of my problem that will fail on my system.

```
class AClass
{
public:
virtual int getTest(int a) {return 0}
}

MOCK_BASE_CLASS (MockAClass, AClass)
{
MOCK_METHOD(getTest, 1, int(int));
}

BOOST_AUTО_TEST_CASE(SomeClassFunctionality)
{

MockAClass  objMockAClass;

MOCK_EXPECT(objMockAClass.getTest).returns(1);
MOCK_EXPECT(objMockAClass.getTest).at_least(1);
objMockAClass.getTest(1);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MOCK_EXPECT(objMockAClass.getTest).returns(1);
MOCK_EXPECT(objMockAClass.getTest).at_least(1);
```

This is actually two expectations. The first one means 'everytime getTest gets called return 1' and the second 'getTest must be called at least one time'.
The problem is that the first one will always match, therefore the second will not have a chance to be triggered.

Comment: Yes that is correct. It processes them as two separate mutually exclusive statements and that is why it fails. Thank you for the support. :)

Answer (score 0):

Тhe problem is solved if separate EXPECT statements are combined in one whole EXPECT statement.

`MOCK_EXPECT(objMockAClass.getTest).at_least(1).returns(1);` - This will make the example work as planned.

Regards,